# How to String a text to show words from a paragraph one after the other?

Tags: c#

I need to String a text to show a different word from a given paragraph consecutively.

i basically want from X time to X time a word to be changed from the word A to B to C to D etc.. in a input paragraph that goes in this order: A B C D etc. So the text gets A, then after X time it gets B then after X time C and so on. But i would need this to be done with a bigger paragraph. So i would need unity in my case to recognise the paragraph, separate all words and change feom one to another on a set time, consecutively. Is this even possible in C#?
I was thinking of something like

```
for(i= 0, i<= numberOfWords, i++)
        if(i%5==0)
   text.Text ="nextWord".ToString();
```

Also seen something like

```
Word Range range = paragraph.Content;
```

But more than this i have no idea.
I am pretty new and im making a game, any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Is the paragraph an existing `string`, or...? Where do you get your input from?

Comment: To be honest i donr really know...i was thinking of saving it in a text and call if i%5==0{ text.word = "nextWord" } but this is a pretty new info for me and im trying to understand it. I was thinking of researching about the Word Range range stuff tommorow

Comment: @RadicalBruh It's unclear what you're having trouble with. I'm not sure what "to String a text" means. Are you asking how to combine a list of words into a single string? Perhaps you can explain more by providing some example input and expected output?

Comment: @Xerillio i basically want from X time to X time a word to be changed from the word A to B to C to D etc.. in a input paragraph that goes in this order: A B C D etc. So the text gets A, then after X time it gets B then after X time C and so on. But i would need this to be done with a bigger paragraph. So i would need unity in my case to recognise the paragraph, separate all words and  change feom one to another on a set time, consecutively. Is this even possible in C#?

Comment: @RadicalBruh You should [edit] your question and paste that entire comment in there. That gives much more info about your aim. The question didn't mention anything about periodically changing the text, so that's a good detail. Perhaps you could look at [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) to see how to repeat a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task ShowText(string paragraph) 
{
  foreach(var word in paragraph.Split(' ')) 
  {
    textComponent.text = word;
    // time for the delay
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
ShowText("A B C D");
```

Comment: I appreciate it. But how do i declare the paragraph?

Comment: You only need to assign your paragraph to a string and then pass it to the function.

Comment: So public string paragraph "A B C D"? Srry if the question is dumb but i never encountered this

Comment: it depends where your paragraph come from.

Comment: I want to makw my own paragraph and write it, but idk how to declare it

Comment: then you just need to declare a string and assign your paragraph into it. and then pass it to the function.

Comment: I found this-  string patagraph = @"this is long text with new lines that I can't show in a comment"; hope it works, thank you for your time

Comment: my visual studio says Task does not exist in the current context

Comment: what target framework are you using?

Comment: idk for sure. I am doing this on unity and Visual Studio recommended  using UnityEditor.VersionControl; and Task is no longer unrecognised. Now it tells me async return nothing thus Show Text is wrong. I am checking the framework now

Comment: i cant figure out where to change or see my target Framework. Are there other ways? :/